# Defender 365 REST API (you don't have any of the required app permissions (Incident.ReadWrite.All, Incident.Read.All) to access resource)

Tags: azure, powershell, privileges, access-rights

I am trying to download list of incidents from Defender 365 (MDATP).

I have a script to get a Bearer Token:

```
. 'Functions\Credentials.ps1'

Function GET_BEARER_TOKEN_FOR_MDATP_AUTHENTICATION {

    $Body = [Ordered] @{
        resource      = "$ResourceApplicationIdUri"
        client_id     = "$ApplicationId"
        client_secret = "$ApplicationSecret"
        grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
    }

    try {
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $OAuthenticationURI -Body $body -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output("unable to get the bearer token") 
        Exit
    }  
    $BearerToken = $Response.access_token
    
    return $BearerToken
}

$xx = GET_BEARER_TOKEN_FOR_MDATP_AUTHENTICATION
$xx | Out-File '.\Bearer_Token.txt'
```

That script worked fine. Today, I have been granted permission to display incidents.

When I try to do that, I get the error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "The application does not have any of the required application permissions (Incident.ReadWrite.All, Incident.Read.All) to access the resource.",
 }
}
```

When I check in the token tester website: https://jwt.ms/

I cannot see those incident.Read.All Roles but only:

```
  "roles": [
    "Alert.ReadWrite.All",
    "AdvancedQuery.Read.All"
  ]
```

Roles have been given by this instruction manual:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender/api-create-app-web?view=o365-worldwide

Many Thanks,
Aster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I have found the issue:

$ResourceApplicationIdUri = 'https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com' (Alerts are allowed)
$ResourceApplicationIdUri = 'https://api.security.microsoft.com' (Incidents are allowed)

Regards,
Aster

Comment: In case others encounter problems...
I had similar to Aster's issue, where my role claims weren't propagating to the token.
It's important, (and not always clear) to set the correct scope when creating the token depending on the API call being made.
My case was for using Advanced Hunting, so the scope is:
    https://api.security.microsoft.com/.default
Whereas using scope:
    https://api.securitycenter.windows.com/.default
will cause the wrong role claims to be added to the token.
Hope this helps someone!